# Why does Map.mapValues change the answer

Tags: scala

Why when I re access the result of a MapValues does it change ? Shouldnt it be immutable.

Consider the following ammonite session.

```
stephen@ import scala.util.Random 
import scala.util.Random
stephen@ Seq("a").map(_ => Random.nextInt) 
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1035918980)
stephen@ res1 
res2: Seq[Int] = List(1035918980)
// re accessing Seq.map doesnt change
stephen@ Map("a" -> "a").mapValues(_ => Random.nextInt()) 
res3: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 653125272)
stephen@ res3 
res4: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> -694232910)
// re accessing Map.mapValues changes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/MapLike.html#mapValues[W](f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.Map[K,W]), `mapValues` returns a view wrapping the original collection, rather than copying the (transformed) data. Since this is just a view, and not a collection in its own right, it needs to be re-evaluated each time you access it.

This is different from, say, `map`, where [the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):Traversable[B]) mentions returning a new collection rather than just a view referencing the original one.

Answer (score 1):

`mapValues` returns a *view* of the Map. The value transformation is applied every time on access, not persisted in memory.